# Using pynput to capture left click and release coordinates

Tags: python, pynput

I am trying to capture the coordinates of when the left click happens, and then the coordinates of when the release of the left click happens. However, in my code, only the "click happened" and the start_click_coords get printed. Nothing else.

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener

# Global variable to store the left click coordinates
start_click_coords = None
rel_click_coords = None

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global start_click_coords
    if button == button.left and pressed:
        print ("click happened!")
        start_click_coords = (x, y)
        print(start_click_coords)
    #endif
#enddef

def on_release(x, y, button):
    global rel_click_coords
    if button == button.left:
        rel_click_coords = (x, y)
        print ("release happened")
        print (rel_click_coords)
        return False
    #endif
#enddef

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Click and drag to select the region for screenshot...")
    # Wait for the left mouse button to be pressed (start the listener)
    with Listener(on_click=on_click, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
        
    print("bye")
    print(start_click_coords)
    print(rel_click_coords)
    
    if coordinates:
        print("Coordinates:", coordinates)
    #endif
#endMain
```

Thanks for your help!